# SendGrid Restful API - 400 Bad Request

Tags: c#, json, sendgrid, dotnet-httpclient, sendgrid-api-v3

I'm working on an integration with SendGrid and managed to get everything working fine using Postman. However, when sending the request from within my C# project I'm getting a 400 bad request error message with the following response:

```
StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://sendgrid.api-docs.io
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type, On-behalf-of, x-sg-elas-acl
Access-Control-Max-Age: 600
X-No-CORS-Reason: https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/API/cors.html
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=600; includeSubDomains
Date: Wed, 15 Sep 2021 08:10:31 GMT
Server: nginx
Content-Length: 191
Content-Type: application/json
```

I've checked my JSON string is valid and the schema is inline with SendGrid's documentation.

I don't know why I'd get an error message about CORS because I'm not using a browser or JavaScript.

Does anyone have any experience with Http requests with SendGrid API?

Below is my C# code for sending the request. I've tried both **PostAsync** and **PostAsJsonAsync** but it makes no difference. I've also tried with and without the 'UserAgent' header and also with and without the 'Host' header.

```
public static async Task<string> SendGridSendMailRequest(string json, string apiToken)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                
        ProductHeaderValue header = new ProductHeaderValue("MyApp", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString());
        ProductInfoHeaderValue user_agent = new ProductInfoHeaderValue(header);
        http_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("*/*"));
        http_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Host = "api.sendgrid.com";
        http_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.Add(user_agent);
        http_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", apiToken);

        // HTTP POST
        //HttpResponseMessage response = await http_client.PostAsync("https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send", content);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await http_client.PostAsJsonAsync("https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send", content);

        // verification & response 
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
           result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
    return result;
}
```

**http_client** is a private static variable as follows:

```
private static HttpClient http_client = new HttpClient();
```

Comment: Fyi there's a C# library for Sendgrid https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp

Comment: I understand this library is available, i've also looked at the StrongGrid library. but at this stage I don't need all the features of a whole library, I just wanted to get basic send mail functionality working.

Comment: It won't cost much to include the library, and it will probably make your life way easier. Also you probably will need another feature from SendGrid some day, who knows..

Answer (score 1):

At first I thought it might be an issue with dropping the Authorization header which can happen on redirection but the issue turned out to be related to TLS. I should have thought about this earlier as I've been stung by the TLS version issue before when using .NET Framework 4.5 or lower.

Here is the final POST request code that now works fine:

```
public static async Task<string> SendGridSendMailRequest(string json, string apiToken)
{
   string result = string.Empty;
   try
   {
      if (http_client == null)
      {
         var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
         {
            AllowAutoRedirect = false,
            SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12 | System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls11 | System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls
         };
         http_client = new HttpClient(handler);
      }
      var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");      
      http_client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.sendgrid.com");
      http_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("*/*"));
      http_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Host = "api.sendgrid.com";
      http_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", apiToken);
      HttpResponseMessage response = await http_client.PostAsync("/v3/mail/send", content);
      if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
      {
          result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
      }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
   }
   return result;
}
```